# Spring MVC Controller parsing emojis as CJK chars

Tags: java, spring, utf-8, cjk

I am trying to post emojis in a simple form. This  is received in the controller as 朗 And I cannot find the reason for this.

Im using spring 3.1.4. 
I have added in the web.xml the following:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

and the filter mapping as well for all /*.

Added the charset in the html and in the form.
Yet when I send over the post, in the browser's console I see the emoji and in the controller inspection, I see the kanji ideograph.

Edit: this is what I see
[text in form post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgKsO.png)
and in the inspector: [code in inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWgpK.png)